# How to get cell reference as address google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, counting

I have a cell address in cell A2 and want to use it as absolute value in another cell B2 which contains a formula.

```
         A                              B
-------------------      ------------------------------
Sheet1!MK65:NO65       =COUNTIF(INDIRECT(A2,FALSE),"=S2/F")
```

How do I get the B2 formula work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with count and array formula:

```
=count(arrayformula(if(indirect(A2)="S2/F",1,"")))
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(A2), "=S2/F")
```

[image: 0]